# Including translations of my bibliography entry titles

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, moderncv, cv

I'm doing my cv in `moderncv` including a list of my publications and working papers with the help of `biblatex`. There are two details about me, though. First, I publish in several languages. Second, I need to have my CV in several languages too. In my English CV, I want the titles of all my non-English publications followed by its English translation in parentheses. For example:

> Ayrton Senna. “Über etwas”. (About something). In: Ergo Sum (15 1990).

And likewise in my Spanish CV:

> Ayrton Senna. “Über etwas”. (Acerca de algo). En: Ergo Sum (15 1990).

The way I'm approaching this is by including both translations in two separate `titleaddon` fields of the bib entry, commenting out the languages I'm not using. For example, when I do my cv in English, I modify the entry as follows:

```
@article{senna1990etwas,
    author      = {Senna, Ayrton},
    title       = {\"Uber etwas},
    titleaddon  = {(About something)},
    %titleaddon = {(Acerca de algo)},
    %titleaddon = {(A proposito di qualcosa)},
    %titleaddon = {(Sobre algo)},
    %titleaddon = {(\'A propos de quelque chose)},
    journal     = {Ego Sum},
    year        = {1990},
    issue       = {15},
}
```

However, it is obviously not a good practice to modify the entry every time I want to build my cv in a different language. Hence, I would rather have separate fields for each translation as follows:

```
@article{senna1990etwas,
    author      = {Senna, Ayrton},
    title       = {\"Uber etwas},
    title-en    = {(About something)},
    title-es    = {(Acerca de algo)},
    title-it    = {(A proposito di qualcosa)},
    title-por   = {(Sobre algo)},
    title-fr    = {(\'A propos de quelque chose)},
    journal     = {Ego Sum},
    year        = {1990},
    issue       = {15},
}
```

With such entry, I would like to use have an optional `translate` field in `\printbibliography` such that `\printbibliography[translate=title-en]` returns the entry with the contents in `title-en` as a `titleaddon` or, even better, right after where the `titleaddon` would be printed.

Here is a minimally working example:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\moderncvstyle{casual}

% PERSONAL DATA
\name{Ayrton}{Senna}
\title{Pilot}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

% PUBLICATIONS
\nocite{*}

% Titles translated into English
\printbibliography[translate=title-en]

% Titles translated into Spanish
%\printbibliography[translate=title-es]

% Titles translated into Italian
%\printbibliography[translate=title-it]

% Titles translated into Portuguese
%\printbibliography[translate=title-por]

% Titles translated into French
%\printbibliography[translate=title-fr]

\end{document}
```

Finally, it is perfectly okay if, instead of the `translate=title-en` argument in `\printbibliography`, a command `\translatetitle{title-en}` is used before `\printbibliography`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to map the `title-en` field (or any other `title-<lang>`) to `titleaddon` programmatically, using `\DeclareSourcemap`. The minimal code which uses your `sample.bib`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
       \step[fieldsource=title-en, fieldtarget=titleaddon]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

As an extension I can suggest to use, for example, the `babel` language name when choosing the title addon. Here is the modified BIB resource `sample2.bib`:

```
@article{senna1990etwas,
    author           = {Senna, Ayrton},
    title            = {\"Uber etwas},
    title-english    = {(About something)},
    title-spanish    = {(Acerca de algo)},
    title-italian    = {(A proposito di qualcosa)},
    title-portuguese = {(Sobre algo)},
    title-french     = {(\'A propos de quelque chose)},
    journal          = {Ego Sum},
    year             = {1990},
    issue            = {15},
}
```

And here is the code which requires only change in the `babel` invocation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample2.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
       \step[fieldsource=title-\languagename, fieldtarget=titleaddon]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

As it is, it uses the French addendum:

[image]

Comment: This does not print the title in english for me. I am using the option [french,...,main=english] in babel.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using the experimental multiscript branches of `biblatex` and `biber` which are designed for this sort of task. Note the benefits which are:

- The `babel` language is switched for the translations to the correct language, ensuring that hyphenation etc. are correct.
- No hard-coded formatting (parens) in the data
- No changing the data when you need to switch translation

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,spanish,italian,portuguese,french,main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@article{senna1990etwas,
    langid                = {ngerman},
    author                = {Senna, Ayrton},
    title                 = {Über etwas},
    title_translation_en  = {About something},
    title_translation_es  = {Acerca de algo},
    title_translation_it  = {A proposito di qualcosa},
    title_translation_pt  = {Sobre algo},
    title_translation_fr  = {Á propos de quelque chose},
    journal               = {Ego Sum},
    year                  = {1990},
    issue                 = {15},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[language=auto,autolang=other,autofieldlang=other]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\def\trtag{en}% <- change translation here

\newbibmacro*{title}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{title}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext[title]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
     \newunit
     \printfield[ttitle][translation][\trtag]{title}%
     \newunit}%
  \printfield{titleaddon}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{ttitle}{(#1)\isdot}

\begin{document}

\cite{senna1990etwas}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```